# Should we assign the job of making and coordinationg calls to Domain Services?

Tags: domain-driven-design, n-tier-architecture

*Application Service* fulfills the commands issued by clients ( ie presentation layer ) by making and coordinating calls to the *Workflows*, *Infrastructure Services*, *Domain Services* and *Domain Entities*.

Is it a common practice to also have few *Domain Services* that do similar job as *Application Services*, meaning they also make and coordinate calls, only difference being they do it at a more fine-grained level ( ie they only make and coordinate calls to other *Domain Services* and *Domain Objects* )?

If yes, any ideas how fine-grained should these *Domain Services* be?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain Services contain domain logic that doesn't particularly fit into any Entity, or that spans across several entities.

One often quoted example is a FundsTransferService. Transferring funds doesn't seem like the responsibility of the BankAccount entity, because that would mean the source account can modify the target account's balance (or the other way around) which seems awkward and might be dangerous. A dedicated TransferFunds() method in a FundsTransferService allows for better separation of concerns and channels all funds movements in a single place.

In that regard, you could say Domain Services coordinate calls on entities and other services, but not in the same sense that Application layer services do IMO. Oftentimes, Application layer services are just boilerplate procedural code while Domain services contain real business rules.

> only difference being they do it at a more fine-grained level

I wouldn't say Domain services are more fine-grained than Application services. They are essentially just in different layers. It's like saying that a Repository is finer grained than a Controller... usually granularity is a measure of to what extent one cohesive operation is split up in smaller parts vs just a big procedure.

Comment: I guess I'm still having major troubles distinguishing between  business rules and use cases. For example, ordering an item is normally considered a use case - but I personally could also interpret ordering an item as a business rule and would thus implement it as a domain service ( which would make and coordinate calls between domain services and domain entities that would check credit, create shipping transaction, manage inventory etc  )?! Uh :(

Comment: There's a fine line between application specific business rules (use cases) and application agnostic business rules (domain). The limit is yours to figure out - however, the more business logic you put in your domain entities, the more reusable it will be and the more streamlined your application services. In your example, if not all orders lead to a shipping transaction (downloadable digital goods for instance, don't), the better solution IMO is to handle that in the domain with polymorphism and leave the application service unaware of that detail rather than adding an "if" in the use case.